# How can I setup cups (cups-pdf backend) to mimic an ESC/POS printer to allow printing to PDF from ePOS software

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, thermal-printer, cups, pos

As the title suggests, I'm trying to mimic popular thermal receipt printers using a Raspberry Pi. My aim is to have the raspberry pi be an option for printing receipts from popular mobile based ePOS systems like Shopify POS, iZettle etc. They all support ECS/POS printers. Once I have the document I want to send it to my webserver for processing using OCR (don't need help with this bit).

Currently, I have a working printer driver (cups-pdf) and I can print directly from the iPad, however, these apps either don't recognise the virtual printer or when I pair it, they fail to print with no logs showing on the printer meaning they're failing to establish a connection.

I've also considered a virtual printer driver app that can run on the iPad directly and just handle the file from the print request by sending it to the web server, however, I don't have much of a starting point with that since I've got more experience working with native Android development.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated and I apologise if I'm vague, I'll be happy to expand if there's anything appearing vague.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KJ what if I chose a specific printer like an mcPrint-2, what's the best way to have that mimicked by the PI? Would I need to write my own backend for cups? Any push in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: @KJ a lot of this goes straight over my head, I'm trying to solve this issue on behalf of a client so I can pay for your assistance if you have the time. You can find my contact details on [Github](https://github.com/mwikala) if you're interested

Comment: I definitely agree with you there. I'll see what I can do with the pre-existing emulator projects. Thanks again